# Kolmogorov Distribution D statistics

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

As far as I have searched the cumulative distribution function of , asymptotically (kolmogorov distribution) is given by Pr(≤)=1−2∑∞=1(−1)−1−222=2√∑∞=1−(2−1)22/(82).

But I can not obtain the proof of it. Could you provide me with the proof or share some documents, links about it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would help if you could format your question in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \sim_{\text{iid}} dF$ and $\hat{F}_n$ the corresponding empirical cumulative distribution.

The Kolmogorov statistic for the assumption $F = G$ is $K_n = \sup |\hat{F}_n(x) - G(x)|$.

Under the null hypothesis $F=G$, one has
$$
\Pr\left(K_n > \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \to 
2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \exp(-2k^2c^2).
$$

This result is proved in Billingsley' book *Convergence of probability measures*. The proof involves the Brownian motion.